# Binary hash representation to HEX/Ascii in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash, theos

I would to log a binary hash representation in the console, using an hex or ascii representation. The algorithm is MD5, so the function is `CC_MD5`

I get the binary hash representation via a Theos tweak, which is working well.

**EDIT:** this tweak intercept the `CC_MD5` call. The call is implemented in the method described below. When `CC_MD5` is called, `replaced_CC_MD5` intercept the call.

The app tested, is a simple app which i made myself and it's using this method to calculate MD5 Hash:

```
- (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input
{
    const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char digest[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call

    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

    return  output;

}
```

The hashing it's ok, and the app returns to me the correct hash for the input

```
input = prova
MD5 Digest = 189bbbb00c5f1fb7fba9ad9285f193d1
```

The function in my Theos Tweak where i manipulate the CC_MD5 function is

**EDIT**: where `data` would be `cStr`, `len` would be `strlen(cStr)` and `md` would be `digest`.

```
static unsigned char * replaced_CC_MD5(const void *data, CC_LONG len, unsigned char *md) {
    CC_LONG dataLength = (size_t) len;
    NSLog(@"==== START CC_MD5 HOOK ====");

    // hex of digest
    NSData *dataDigest = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)md length:(NSUInteger)CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSLog(@"%@", dataDigest);

    // hex of string
    NSData *dataString = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)data length:(NSUInteger)dataLength];
    NSLog(@"%@", dataString);

    NSLog(@"==== END CC_MD5 HOOK ====");

    return original_CC_MD5(data, len, md);

}
```

The log of `dataString` it's ok: `70726f76 61` which is the HEX representation of `prova`
The log of `dataDigest` is `e9aa0800 01000000 b8c00800 01000000` which is, if i understood, the **binary** hash representation.

How can i convert this representation to have the MD5 Hash digest?

Comment: Are you not displaying `md` in `replaced_CC_MD5` *before* you call `original_CC_md` which provides its value?

Comment: Exact, more or less :). I'm displaying the **binary** hash representation, i think, of `md` but i would the hex or ascii representation of this value. `original_CC_MD5` it's called to return the normal function, after my stuffs

Comment: The value you are displaying is the *hex* of 16 bytes passed to `replaced_CC_MD5`. There is nothing in your question os show where that value comes from, and based on `CC_MD5` it looks like `md` is an *output* parameter, hence my first comment. However if you are passing in a meaningful value you need to edit your question to show what it is, where it is coming from, etc.

Comment: Sorry. I thought that i've wrote it. Now i've edited: i hope that it is more clear. Sorry again, and tnx.

Comment: So back to my first comment, you are printing out 'md' in the second case *before* you call `original_CC_md`, so it's just random garbage or whatever was in `md` peviously.

Comment: Yep, i thought the same thing. Finally now works: i've to call the `original_CC_MD5` at begin. After that call, `md` is what i expect! I think that `CC_MD5` original function, at intercept's moment, not end its work yet. Because the result is always the same, so i dont think that is garbage, but is another type of representation. Obviously not sure about it! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: @CRD for the answer...i write it, or you? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `replaced_CC_MD5` you are displaying `md` *before* the call to `original_CC_MD5` which sets its value. What you are seeing is therefore random data (or whatever was last stored in `md`).

Move the call to `original_CC_MD5` to before the display statement and you should see the value you expect. (You'll of course need to save the result of the call in a local so you can return the value in the `return` statement.)